# Importing contacts with a campaign

Tags: contact, campaign

I need to import a bunch of contacts. One of the columns in my .csv has a campaign. I do not see a campaign field in the contact object. Does that makes sense? Am I supposed to first do the contact insert then get the contact id from the success file and then import them into a campaign or is there a way to put the campaign id into the contact object? Can someone explain?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contact is relatedo to Campaign via CampaingMember object. You can import contacts first and add them to Campaign. Or in Campaign you can import new Campaing Members from csv file